# Popular Hashtags

Tags: php, mysql

Okay this is what I have so far; basically it selects the most popular hash tags and echo's them out in DESC however when it echo's them out it prints out like the following how do I change this;

**What Gets Echoed Out** 
This is what appears on the page

```
Array ( [#conversation] => 1 [#new] => 1 )
```

**Select Statement** How do I get it to just echo out the hash tags.

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT subject, count(usr_users.subject)as subjectCount FROM usr_users 
    GROUP BY usr_users.subject
    ORDER BY subjectCount DESC
    ")or die(mysql_error());
$maxLines = 10;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $str1 = $row['subject'];
    $a = explode(' ', $str1);
    $size = sizeof($a);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $v = $a[$i];
        if ($v[0] == '#') {
            $hash_arr[] = $v;
        }
    }
    if (0 == $maxLines)
        break;
}
$t = array_count_values($hash_arr);
ksort($t);
print_r($t);
?>
```

Comment: @chris85 how is this achieved? sorry new to PHP

Comment: Answer posted demonstrating how to use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) doesn't do what you are thinking it does. You want to iterate through the array to do that use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Demo:

```
$array = array("#conversation", "#new");
$t=array_count_values($array);
foreach($t as $hash => $count) {
    echo $hash . "\n";
}
```

Output:

> #conversation
>   #new

Demo: https://eval.in/501267

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT subject, count(usr_users.subject)as subjectCount FROM usr_users 
GROUP BY usr_users.subject
ORDER BY subjectCount DESC
")or die(mysql_error());
$maxLines = 10;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
$str1= $row['subject'];
$a=explode(' ',$str1);
$size=sizeof($a);
for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
$v=$a[$i];
if($v[0]=='#'){
$hash_arr[]=$v;
}
}
if(0==$maxLines)
break;
}
$t=array_count_values($hash_arr);
ksort($t);
//print_r($t);
while (list($key, $val) = each($t)) {
                if(!empty($val)){
                    echo $fields= $key ."count is->";
                    echo $valset=  $val ;// if you want to comment this value then comment it .
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            }
// or
//foreach($t as $row=>$value ){echo $row."<br>";}
?>
```

or use foreach instred of wile

```
foreach($t as $row=>$value ){
echo $row."<br>";
}
```

if you want to replace # from a value the use

```
foreach($t as $row=>$value ){

echo  str_replace('#','',$row) ;
echo "</br>";

}
```

result:

```
  conversation
  new
```